# DevExtreme Reactive chart

Tags: javascript, charts, devextreme

Im using DevExtreme Reactive (@devexpress/dx-react-chart-material-ui) for my charts. When there is a values, chart is fine (picture 1), but when Im passing 0 values, value axis is jumping up (picture 2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: small fragment of code 
https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-morning-h8stwy?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. `<ValueScale name="value" modifyDomain={() => [0, 10]} />` passing callback to modifyDomain is solving issue.